# md select after local storage load required attribute not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material, ng-storage

I am working on an angular web page on which I have used angular material controls. I have a md select control which I have defined as follows:

```
<md-select ng-model="organization" required="true" name="organization">
    <md-option value="">Organization</md-option>
    <md-option ng-repeat="organization in organizationDescriptions" value="{{organization.text}}">
        {{organization.text}}
    </md-option>
</md-select>
```

This lives on a parent form whose $invalid property controls the behavior of a button. Whenever I select a value from the dropdown, the form becomes valid and the button is activated. If there is no value selected then the button is disabled.

However, I also implemented local storage using [ngstorage](https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage). What this does, is that it automatically manages the state of the properties of the scope and saves them into the local storage of the browser. This means that whenever I refresh the page the same dropdown value is selected. This works completely fine.

However when performing a refresh, the $invalid property of the form is now set to true (even though the md select value is correctly set). How can I solve this?

Comment: Could you try it with HEAD(version) as I advise in my answer?

Comment: Please, see my edit: your issue has been solved in the the recently released public version 1.1.0. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

> **EDIT**: The issue is already solved in the recently released public version [1.1.0](https://github.com/angular/material/releases/tag/v1.1.0)

I've been facing with the same issue, and I can confirm you that is an `angular-material` bug that is solved in the `HEAD(master)` version. 
Hopefully it will be released in the next (and long awaited...) `1.1.0` release. There is some closed issues about it. [Example](https://github.com/formly-js/angular-formly-templates-material/issues/42)

> - [Plunker](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OXoONP?editors=1010#0) with angular-material 1.1.0-rc5 (it fails)
> - [Plunker](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KrxyRv) with angular-material HEAD(master) (it's working fine)

I've been wasting some hours... so hope it helps other people.

(With attached plunkers I need to put some code...Your code will work like a charm with the next angular-material release):

```
<md-select ng-model="organization" required="true" name="organization">
    <md-option value="">Organization</md-option>
    <md-option ng-repeat="organization in organizationDescriptions" value="{{organization.text}}">
        {{organization.text}}
    </md-option>
</md-select>
```